# How can I get code coverage from my Golang Server?

Tags: testing, go, server, code-coverage

I am using goconvey and other tools to get the code coverage.
This produces a test coverage report but it only shows the coverage for the test case code.
API is hosted on the a Golang server.
I would like to know how much server side code is covered by my
`tests(unit,integreation,system tests)`.
How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do:

```
godep go test -coverprofile cover.out `go list ./... | grep -v vendor`
go tool cover -html=cover.out
```

That generates a coverage report and then opens a browser window to view it.